# weird space before prompt using tmux on Mac OS Lion

Tags: zsh, tmux

it just happened on my Lion system, I am using zsh with tmux

normal in the zsh shell

[image]

double space in tmux screen

[image: wider indention]

am I missing some config in zsh or tmux?

Comment: I removed the vim tag since there is no relation with Vim. Or am I missing something in the question?

Comment: it's ok @lucapette I will post the vim problem in a new question, thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Start tmux with the -u option for unicode functionality. See [this issue](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/559).

From `man tmux`:

> -u
>
> tmux attempts to guess if the terminal is likely to support UTF-8 by checking the first of the LC_ALL, LC_CTYPE and
>   LANG environment variables to be set for the string "UTF-8".  This is not always correct: the -u flag explicitly
>   informs tmux that UTF-8 is supported.
>
> If the server is started from a client passed -u or where UTF-8 is detected, the utf8 and status-utf8 options are
>                      enabled in the global window and session options respectively.

Comment: exactly same with yours, I changed to another theme, same problem, but it's fine to just use zsh, only in the tmux screen, it's wider

Comment: add one more option ``set-option -g utf-8 on`

Comment: Looks strange to me, but `tmux -u` has done the job, `set-option` lines were not enough.

Answer (score 7):

I ran into this problem with `zsh`, `byobu` and `tmux`.

To fully solve it:

- Add the following to `~/.zshrc`:

  `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
  export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`
- Add `-u` after `byobu-lauch` in `~/.zprofile`:

  `_byobu_sourced=1 . /usr/bin/byobu-launch -u`
- Add the following to `~/.byobu/.tmux.conf`:

  `set-option -g utf-8 on`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I changed system language to English. When I use command `locale` all fields was empty. And when I set format language in preferences (Language & Region -> Advanced) to Russian - command `locale` was with filled values and in tmux it was ok.