# oh my zsh showing weird on tmux with unknown white space

Tags: tmux

I installed oh-my-zsh on a ubuntu server, and it works OK with user terminal.
[on normal zsh terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ij2xE.png)
But when I use tmux, some weird and **unknown white spaces** occur before typing any command.
[on tmux's zsh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBeBO.png)
any help will be appreciated!!!

Comment: questions solved after finding [Q1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237462/weird-space-before-prompt-using-tmux-on-mac-os-lion/25881558) and [Q2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/832571/tmux-shows-double-the-amount-of-space-in-front-of-command-prompt).

Comment: whether use `tmux -u` or add
```export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 

export LANG=en_US.UTF-8```
to ~/.zshrc file. don't forget to `source ~/.zshrc`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/718583/329638) worked for me. I had the same error from the link when running `clear` in the terminal and the below answer fixed that issue along with this issue.

> An approach that has always worked for me in this situation (when
> ssh'ing onto a foreign VM etc) is simply typing
>
> `export TERM=xterm`
>
> You can also add this as a .profile entry on the
> foreign box too if permission allows to make it permanent.